# Scripted Authentication for Autodesk Forge TokenFlex API

Tags: autodesk-forge

This question pertains to the Autodesk Forge TokenFlex Usage API.  We would like to run an application that pulls data on a scheduled basis.  Our understanding is that the Forge TokenFlex API requires 3 Legged authentication.  We have successfully adapted the Autodesk GitHub code sample "A Forge Python Script Demonstrating new TokenFlex Usage API" to pull our data but this requires 3-Legged Authentication.

Is there a way to pull data using the TokenFlex Usage API without requiring user intervention for Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately TokenFlex requires 3 legged auth for enhanced security purposes.

However you can minimize user intervention but rotating the token periodically in your backend using the `refresh_token` that comes with the token to [get refreshed tokens implicitly](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/refreshtoken-POST/) and store them securely (encryption recommended for security reasons) where your script can use them, see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/gettoken-POST/#example) for details